# Rspec generator to create a *_spec.rb file to test a PORO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

[This website](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/generators) lists the various `generators` available to create spec files for specific rails files.

I know how to generator a spec file for a model.

Ex: `rails generate rspec:model Customer` creates this file:

```
#spec/models/customer_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Customer, type: :model do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

I created a service: `MYPORO`.  It is a PORO (plain old ruby object), located at `app/services/my_poro.rb`.

How do I generate a `spec` file in order to create tests for the `MyPoro` class and its instances?  The biggest issue I have is I don't know what `type` to provide, because it is not a `:model`.  I would just manually create the file, but again: I don't know what `:type` to provide inside the file.

Comment: Maybe you can write a generator? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: @CrawfordWynnes that might be worth doing, but I'm not too familiar with Rspec.  What does the `type` argument do?  Is it important?  Could I just leave it out and would that work?

Comment: I think the generators are in the rspec-rails gem. You could replace rspec:model with service_test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No "Type" Required for POROs

> The biggest issue I have is I don't know what type to provide, because it is not a :model. I would just manually create the file, but again: I don't know what :type to provide inside the file.

You don't need to specify a type for plain Ruby objects. The :type tells the RSpec Rails extensions loaded by the *rails_helper* module (installed by [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails)) how to run certain types of tests for models, routes, and so forth.

I generally still load *rails_helper* instead of *spec_helper* for these types of specs, but in most cases you should be able to simplify to something like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Customer do
  pending "insert tests on your non-Rails Customer class"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`touch spec/services/my_poro_spec.rb` ?

You don't need generators for everything. ;)

Comment: Please see revised question.